# RequireJS Cannot Redeclare Class Error

Tags: error, requirejs

I just updated all of my add-ons. I came up with an error during the update relating to Blueprints. Now, when I try to visit the Extensions page in the CP, I get this error. Any ideas?

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class RJS_Hooks in /home/user/subdomains/dev/system/expressionengine/third_party/requirejs/core/RJS_Hooks.php on line 109
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does it work if you remove RequireJS-for-EE? If you cant remove it from the CP, you can go into the DB and find the exp_extensions table and remove the RequireJS row.

Comment: So the error took over the whole extensions page so I wasn't able to uninstall that way, but I deleted the DB entry and was able to get into the Extensions page just fine. I re-enabled RequireJS and was immediately hit with the same error as before. Hmmm.

Comment: It almost sounds like another add-on may be loading another version of requirejs before yours tries to or something?

Comment: EE v2.5.5 (Don't have guts to upgrade to v2.6 just quite yet :-) and RequireJS v1.4

Comment: I agree, I think it is an issue with another addon using RequireJS (or a copy/paste of its injection technique) internally. I'll have to add a check for the existence of RequireJS, but do you mind telling me what extensions you have activated?

Comment: Here are all of my enabled Extensions...

Comment: Assets / Better Workflow / Blueprints / Event Helper / Export_it / Field Editor / Freebie / Google Maps for ExpressionEngine / Libraree / Low Events / Low Reorder / Low Search / Low Variables / Matrix / Minimee / MX Title Control / Playa / SafeCracker / Safecracker Registration / Securit:ee / Stash / Structure / Zenbu